# Pairing Bluetooth LE Devices for both Windows & Linux

Tags: ubuntu, windows, bluetooth

I'm trying to pair my Logitech G603 Bluetooth mouse with both windows 10 and Ubuntu. I followed [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/568521/simpler-method-of-pairing-bluetooth-devices-for-both-windows-linux) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402488/dual-boot-bluetooth-le-low-energy-device-pairing) without success. I think that the problem is how the export of the Key from windows, since from chntpw I get different values than what I get from Windows itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds that with Linux 5.9+ there are some "issues" with the Bluetooth stack. Removing `[IdentityResolvingKey] Key=...` fix the issue of bluetooth mouse that after the reboot not connect anymore.

Ref: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth#Problems_with_all_BLE_devices_on_kernel_5.9+