# Bluetooth pairing in Windows and Manjaro/Arch dual boot

Tags: arch-linux, windows, dual-boot, manjaro, bluetooth

As explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255509/bluetooth-pairing-on-dual-boot-of-windows-linux-mint-ubuntu-stop-having-to-p) when rebooting into the other OS you need to pair again because the bluetooth mac address is constant, and new keys are generated that overwrite the existing keys on the device. However, some of the solutions to this have become outdated (including on the Arch website at time of writing) as explained below.