# Bluetooth Pairing on Dual Boot of Windows & Linux Mint/Ubuntu - Stop having to Pair Devices - Not working

Tags: drivers, windows, dual-boot, keyboard, bluetooth

I've tried everything mentioned on the answers mentioned in the following post:
[Bluetooth Pairing on Dual Boot of Windows & Linux Mint/Ubuntu - Stop having to Pair Devices](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255509/bluetooth-pairing-on-dual-boot-of-windows-linux-mint-ubuntu-stop-having-to-p)

But I've made no progress. A few details about my system:
Keyboard: Logitech K380 (Bluetooth)
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

Windows 10 (Latest edition as of writing this post)

After changing my keys in linux to the ones from windows, the keyboard connects for a fraction of a second, before disconnecting, and I'm unable to understand why. My keyboard has 3 profiles that I can switch from and I tried all combinations of profile choice in windows and linux.

I've spent quite a few hours on this and any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if I am missing any details that might help.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same keyboard and successfully connect to triple boot laptop. Make sure you follow the sequence.

1. Connect to both OS with the same bluetooth options. Eg: If you connect Linux to F2, you must also connect Windows to F2.
2. In the last step, after edit the linkkey in Linux, try to boot twice. If it doesnt work, reconnect the keyboard with F2, it will ask for passcode and enter it accordingly. And your keyboard should work fine.
3. After that, please check again the linkkey in Linux and make sure it doesnt change to a new one. Or else you also need to change again the linkkey in Windows. This is a never ending cycle.