# Using Bluetooth keyboard in rEFInd with dual boot (Windows/Linux)

Tags: bluetooth, refind

I'm running a dual boot setup on my PC where I have Windows 11 installed on one SSD and Zorin OS (Linux) installed on another SSD. I use rEFInd as the bootloader, that lets me choose which system to go to when booting. For this, I need to use the keyboard.

I recently bought an Apple Magic Keyboard (gen 1) and realised that this will probably be a challenge to get working with rEFInd. Additionally, I have some problems with having to pair the keyboard each time I change OS, but found [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255509/bluetooth-pairing-on-dual-boot-of-windows-linux-mint-ubuntu-stop-having-to-p) that hopefully will fix that, where you would make Windows and Linux share pairing keys for the keyboard.

But back to rEFInd: is it possible to make rEFInd connect to the keyboard via Bluetooth? And could it somehow be done in a similar way to the link above, where Windows, Linux and rEFInd would share the same pairing keys?

Having to re-pair the keyboard each time with either the bootloader or when switching OS would really make things very cumbersome, but maybe it's impossible to prevent?